# Process (python script -> py2exe ) InputStream is NULL until Process ends

Tags: java, python, multithreading, process, py2exe

I am trying to catch on fly `Process` output like below:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "myexec.exe");

        p = builder.start();

        InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(i, "US-ASCII");

        int ch = 32;

        do {
           System.out.print(ch);
        } while ((ch = r.read()) != -1);

    }
}.start();
```

As I see, while `Process` is running `ch == null`, when `Process` is terminated all missing chars are suddenly printed.

How can I read output during `Process` running?

Comment: You'll need a thread to read the output.

Comment: Why ? the same situation is when i use another thread to capture output like:            p = builder.start();
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream());
outputGobbler.start();

Comment: Yep. In that, outputGobbler is a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got the solution.
myexec.exe was an executable python file produced by py2exe.

due to [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)
i put `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print` function and problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

You need to spawn additional thread to consume data from stream and wait for process to complete in main thread:

```
...
p = builder.start();

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        InputStream i = p.getInputStream();
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(i, "US-ASCII");

        int ch = 32;

        do {
            System.out.print(ch);
        } while ((ch = r.read()) != -1);
    }
}.start();

// wait for process to complete while thread above consumes data
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: unfortunately it makes no diference..still process output is visible only when process is finished

Comment: Then maybe process produces output right before completion.